# Silverlight tutorial of Cartman

Tags: wpf, silverlight, svg, vector-graphics

Few months ago, I have came across a Silverlight tutorial of Eric Cartman (South Park). Which used the vector image from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Eric.svg to animate him. However, I cannot seem to find that tutorial any longer.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was it this? - [Using SVG Assets in Expression Design](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/5/0/550ed7a1-03fe-4542-9a14-140bfdbef2f0/TH_EX_Design_SVG.wmv)

Comment: That is it mate! Thanks a lot. I am horrible at searching the web I guess.